# Account lost association with almost all sites

Tags: support, login, account-recovery

I have a strange problem with my account. 
My PC lost the association to all Stack Exchange sites (including Stack Exchange) but one.

Only on Stack Overflow it recognizes me correctly (my user there is user1708042).
I don't remember the password, but on this PC I'm kept logged in with my history thanks to the cookie I guess.

If I go under "My Logins" I see 
"Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts" and there is nothing associated but a button that offers to add other logins, e.g., via Google.

I did try to do a password recovery but but what happened is that it created a new identity (this where I'm posting from: user339369).

How can I associate my working account (user1708042) with my e-mail and assign to it a working password?

Comment: Check out the [merge accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) page in the help center. Merging your old account with the one you accidentally created should fix this for you.

Comment: thanks solved. Strange that one can delete the stack exchange credentials at all, and that later one is offered only the option to add a login with other sites authentication mechanisms.